# Google Cloud Storage NodeJS Library, createReadStream adds invalid first character

Tags: node.js, csv, google-cloud-platform, stream

If I use file.download() on the entire file, there is no issue. So I know it's not the file itself. But if I stream the file, I get an invalid first character.

```js
async readFileStream(bucket, filename) {
    const myBucket = this.storage.bucket(bucket);
    const file = myBucket.file(filename);
    const stream = await file.createReadStream();

    stream.on('data', async (data) => {
        console.log('data');
        debugger;
    });

    return stream;
}
```

The data

```
data.toString()
'﻿start_date,email,sales
```

Then `data.toString()[0]` is `''` instead of `'s'`

Any ideas what could possibly be creating this invisible character? And how to get rid of it?

Comment: What's the file encoding? Did you try locally?

Answer (score 1):

So this took me down a rabbit hole. The problem was actually Excel adding a BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the beginning of a CSV. Using PapaParse for NodeJS we modified the header to trim() whitespace, which took care of the BOM.

So the issue was with our file, and not GCS. If you use GCS file.download() they strip the BOM apparently, but not when using readStream